# recover from test timeout panic in golang

Tags: go

How to recover from test timeout panic in golang?

main.go:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main()  {
    fmt.Println("main")
}
```

main_test.go:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "testing"
    "time"
)

func TestMain(m *testing.M) {
    defer PanicHandle() // this doesn't work
    retCode := m.Run()
    fmt.Println("retCode", retCode)
}

func PanicHandle() {
    if r := recover(); r != nil {
        fmt.Println("panic handled")
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}

func Test1(t *testing.T) {
    defer PanicHandle()
    fmt.Println("test1")
    time.Sleep(time.Second)
}
```

And run with command:

```
go test -c -o test && ./test -test.timeout 1s
```

I'm using `recover()` in `TestMain` and in `Test1`. But the panic `panic: test timed out after 1s` is not recovered anyway.

## Update

To simplify the code I refactored it:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "testing"
    "time"
)

func TestMain(m *testing.M) {
    defer func() {
        if r := recover(); r != nil {
            fmt.Println("panic handled")
            os.Exit(1)
        }
    }()
    retCode := m.Run()
    fmt.Println("retCode", retCode)
}

func Test1(t *testing.T) {
    defer func() {
        if r := recover(); r != nil {
            fmt.Println("panic handled")
            os.Exit(1)
        }
    }()
    fmt.Println("test1")
    time.Sleep(time.Second)
    panic("panic in test1")
}
```

Usual panic is handled:
go test -v -timeout **2**s

```
=== RUN   Test1
test1
panic handled
exit status 1
```

But timeout panic is not:
go test -v -timeout **1**s

```
=== RUN   Test1
test1
panic: test timed out after 1s

goroutine 21 [running]:
panic(0xe5520, 0xc42008e490)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:500 +0x1a1
testing.startAlarm.func1()
    /usr/local/go/src/testing/testing.go:918 +0x10b
created by time.goFunc
    /usr/local/go/src/time/sleep.go:154 +0x44

goroutine 1 [chan receive]:
testing.(*T).Run(0xc42009a0c0, 0x10cf65, 0x5, 0x11b928, 0x58135)
    /usr/local/go/src/testing/testing.go:647 +0x316
testing.RunTests.func1(0xc42009a0c0)
    /usr/local/go/src/testing/testing.go:793 +0x6d
testing.tRunner(0xc42009a0c0, 0xc42003fdb0)
    /usr/local/go/src/testing/testing.go:610 +0x81
testing.RunTests(0x11b938, 0x191230, 0x1, 0x1, 0x27be3)
    /usr/local/go/src/testing/testing.go:799 +0x2f5
testing.(*M).Run(0xc42003fee8, 0x11b930)
    /usr/local/go/src/testing/testing.go:743 +0x85
github.com/ypapax/deferPanic.TestMain(0xc42003fee8)
```

Comment: `recover()` must be called in a defered function. Your code does not work.

Comment: @Volker I call recover with defer: `defer PanicHandle()`. Usual panic is recovered in my code if I add `panic("panic")` to `Test1` after `defer PanicHandle()` line. But timeout panic is not recovered.

Comment: From https://golang.org/ref/spec#Handling_panics: "The return value of recover is nil if any of the following conditions holds: [...] recover was not called directly by a deferred function." Your simplified code shows proper use of recover. Note that the "timeout panic" does not occur from _inside_ your code so it cannot be recovered.

Comment: @Volker To clarify, where exactly is the "timeout panic" occurring from? Is it from the `go` binary (not the test binary)? Or rather from a separate goroutine started by the `go` binary which is separate from the test binary routine?